# XmlInverseReference, Hibernate, JAXWS and Moxy

Tags: hibernate, jax-ws, moxy

I can not seem to get moxy working with JAX-WS web services and hibernate. Despite what I do, `@XMLInverseReference` does not work. I'd expect it to fill in the `application` variable on a `Site`. What am I doing or understanding wrong?

I receive: `org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: Site.application`. If I add `@XMLElement` to `Site.application`, then I get a circular reference exception from JAXB.

It's worth mentioning all the marshaling and unmarshalling is handled by the JAX-WS WSServlet end point.

Also I verified my jaxb.properties is working correctly by doing the following:

```
public class Run {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(JAXBContext.newInstance(Site.class).getClass());
    }
}
```

---

Application:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "dbo", name = "Applications")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement
public class Application {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @RemoteProperty
    @XmlElement
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "code", nullable = false, unique = true)
    @NaturalId
    @XmlElement
    private String code;
    @Column(name = "name")
    @XmlElement
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "application", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cache(usage = org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    @Cascade(value = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DELETE, CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN})
    @Sort(type = SortType.NATURAL)
    @XmlElement
    private Set<Site> sites = new TreeSet<Site>();
}
```

Site:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "dbo", name = "Sites")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement
public class Site implements Identifiable<Integer>, Comparable<Site> {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "address", unique = true)
    @NaturalId(mutable = true)
    @XmlID
    private String address;
    @Column(name = "ssl")
    @XmlAttribute(required = true)
    private boolean ssl;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "applicationCode", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "code")
    @XmlInverseReference(mappedBy = "code")
    private Application application;
}
```

jaxb.properties

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

Answer (score 0):

JAX-WS implementations do not necessarily respect the JAXB.properties.  If you are using WebLogic 12.1.1 or GlassFish 3.1.2 the following will help:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/12/eclipselink-moxy-is-jaxb-provider-in.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/02/glassfish-312-is-full-of-moxy.html

Comment: We are using Tomcat, I'll have a look however.